# Replace/Remove characters from XSL

Tags: xslt-2.0

**My code**

```
<xsl:element name="g:google_product_category" >
    <xsl:value-of select="google_shopping_category" />
</xsl:element>
```

**Output**

```
<g:google_product_category>2826 - Hardware > Building Materials > Flooring & Carpet<br /></g:google_product_category>
```

**Problem**

I need to remove `<br />` from the end of the value

**Notes**

From what I've read, there are several methods for accomplishing my task:

1. Stripping HTML
2. Replacing text with blank
3. Stripping last few characters from value

However, I'm unable to follow the instructions without error.

Comment: Please show us minimal but complete samples of XML and XSLT to allow us to reproduce the problem. I don't see how an `xsl:value-of` could construct a `br` result element.

Comment: I just realised I missed a " when creating this post. The google_shopping_category value refers to a DB value of "2826 - Hardware > Building Materials > Flooring & Carpet<br />". Unfortunately, it's the DB entry that contains the annoying <br />.

Comment: So what is the output format, plain text? I don't see an simply `xsl:value-of` creating a `br` result element with output methods `html` or `xml`, unless you also use `disable-output-escaping="yes"`. As for stripping that `br`, which XSLT 2 processor do you use? Any chance you can move to XSLT 3 (e.g. Saxon 9.8). Then you could use `<xsl:value-of select="parse-xml-fragment(google_shopping_category)"/>`